# MVC passing ID from view to a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

If I have the following on the view

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.sLevelid) 

Controller 
Public actionresult GetName(int id)
{


}
```

How can I pass the id to a controller so I can create a linq query to get the name the id belongs to on a separate table in the database?
thanks in advance

Comment: The separate table, where would you display it? New view or the current view?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this in your view:

```
// GetName here refers to the name of the action on your controller
@{ Html.RenderAction("GetName", new { id = @Model.sLevelid }); }
```

Then your controller action would look like this:

```
public PartialViewResult GetName(int id)
{
    var model = // Use Linq to get whatever you need by the id

    return PartialView("_GetName", model);
}
```

You'd then create a partial view in your `~/Views/Shared/` folder, giving it the name `_GetName.cshtml`.  That view would then look something like this:

```
@model TheTypeOfModelGetNameReturns

<div>@Model.SomeProperty</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it will work if you use the name "sLevelid" in the Controller method signature:

```
Public actionresult GetName(int sLevelid)
```

Then you can use this id to find the object with a linq query. This works because the name in the form post matches the name of the int in the signature, so the framework automatically binds it to the int variable.

Also, check that the View is called "GetName.cshtml", as it has to match the name of the method, under normal circumstances.